# Visual Studio 2022 Stuck in Authorization Loop

Tags: visual-studio

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2022 that continually asks me to re-authorize my Microsoft account in a loop, which seems like it is once per project in the solution.

This happens if I want to do anything with source control (the project is in Azure), build, or publish.

It prompts me for my Microsoft username and password continually in a loop until it finally ends up doing what I want to do (for example, build).

The next time I go to build, it goes back through the same authorization process.

This makes it impossible to get any work done.  We do not have a Microsoft support contract and it seems they do not offer per-issue support, it now requires either a contract or a subscription.  I just want to resolve this single issue.

Has anyone seen this or have any suggestions as to how I can get out of this loop?  It doesn't cache the credentials, it constantly re-prompts me.

Thanks.

[image: Login Screen]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this appears to be with a work account and computer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem has plagued many Visual Studio versions and there have been
various solutions found. Here are some of them:

- In the "Account Settings" window click "Account options",
  change the drop-down for "Add and reauthenticate account using:"
  from "Embedded web browser" to "System web browser".
- Launch *Tools|Options|NuGet Package Manager|Package Sources*
  and deselect all items in the list.
- If using a custom package source that gives access based on the account,
  use the browser to browse to that package source, and log in there.

If none of these solutions solved the problem, you could report the problem.
See the article
[Report a problem with the Visual Studio product or installer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).

Comment: awesome. works like a charm. thanks

Comment: VS 2022 Account Settings set to System web browser. Worked for me. :)